# Retrieve binary field in SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to save a pdf file in a `varbinary(MAX)` type column, and I use a `TableAdapter` in SQL Server. I wrote this code to insert:

```
DataSet1TableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter tblpdf = new DataSet1TableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter();

byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfDocument1.FilePath);
tblpdf.InsertQuery(b);
```

and it works correctly, but I have a problem retrieving the PDF fro the binary column. I use this code:

```
byte[] c= (byte[]) table1TableAdapter.ScalarQuery(txtSearch.Text); //with txtsearch box i search a field

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfDocument1.FilePath, c);
```

and I get an error

> the path could not be null

and I think it means that my "c" variable is null and `ScalarQuery` does not work correctly.

Please help me

Comment: no, it's probably pdfDocument1.FilePath that's null, e.g. you're trying to write a file to an undefined/empty path.

Comment: @MarcB: If that were true, wouldn't the `ReadAllBytes` fail as well?

Comment: depends on if those two snippets are from the same program blocks or not.

Comment: set a breakpoint at the WriteAllBytes line and inspect if pdfDocument1 or pdfDocument1.FilePath is null

Comment: pdfDocument1 is a tool from a component that i add to my program to access pdf documents and it works correctly, i checked it

Comment: @MarcB: Yes, ur right, i change this line: System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfDocument1.FilePath, c); to this one System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\anne.pdf", c); and it works correctly. and the question is : how can i save c in to string variable?(i know its simple but i'm newbie)

Comment: actually i want to do something like this: System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(ff, c);
pdfDocument1.FilePath = ff;

Answer (score 0):

@MarcB: Yes, you are right, i change this line:

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfDocument1.FilePath, c);

to this one:

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\serah.pdf", c);

and it works correctly.

but now the question is how can i use "WriteAllBytes" to write c into a variable in the code, actually i want to do something like this:

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(ff, c);

pdfDocument1.FilePath = ff;

Comment: If you have a new question, you ought to ask it *as* a question, not inside of an answer. And if you want to avoid hard coding an actual path when pulling the data back out of the database, you either need to look into creating a temporary file or (possibly) the `pdfDocument1` component has a facility that allows you to pass the data without using a file - but since we don't know what component you're using, it's impossible to say whether this second approach could work.